# How can I get a Dell 1320c printer to work in Ubuntu 1804

Tags: 18.04, printing

I followed the directions in Ubuntu help and installed my Dell 1320c network printer by typing printer in "Activities" choosing to intall drivers from the Generic list as a generic PCL laser printer. It seems to be working in that toner levels are displayed, but when I try to print a document although a message appears saying that the doc is printing and then a printing completed message nothing happens except that the printer starts up and I hear the motor run for a few seconds if the printer has been idle but there is no paper movement and nothing prints.  If the printer is already warmed up all that happens is that the on light blinks once.  The printer works OK from a Windows computer so it is not faulty.